# String to DateTime python

Tags: python, datetime

`2020-03-04`

I am extracting this from a file I read into a pandas Dataframe and want to transform it to `datetime` before I add a column and add the `datetime` to each row.

How can I transform this `string` to `datetime`?

Sorry for the newbie question, never dealt with this before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only have date value and it is in `string` form, you can use `.strptime()` methods of `datetime.datetime`.

This is how you can do it :

```
from datetime import datetime
myDate = "2020-03-04"
datetime.strptime(myDate, "%Y-%m-%d")

OutPut -> datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

import time

time=time.strftime('%m%d%H%M%Y.%S')

so the variable time contains the string content of the time.